# Super cool progress bar in Symfony

Tags: symfony

In [Symfony Progress Bar documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) there is an example image of a super-cool bar. Unfortunately, it looks like the rest of doc doesn't explain how to get such result.
Here is the image, in case you miss it:

[image]

How can I get it?

Comment: Link is broken. Use [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html)

Comment: I think code for this would be really complicated, but it is possible. The image is so high end just to show the best you can do with this component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/master/Tests/Helper/ProgressBarTest.php) source. I think it might be helpful for you.